# Azure DevOps and Azure Resource Deployment: make securestring output available

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

**Context:**

I create a storage account via an ARM template with the following output (among others):

```
"storageAccountKey": {
  "type": "securestring",
  "value": "[listKeys(parameters('storageAccountName'), '2018-02-01').keys[0].value]"
}
```

In a next step I convert the deployment output to Azure DevOps environments variables to make them accessible for a subsequent PowerShell task.

**Problem:**

With an output of type 'string' this works fine, but not with the type 'securestring' as the value is not made available in the deployment output string.

**Question:**

How can I make an output of type 'securestring' of an ARM Deployment available as secure Azure DevOps environment variable?

Thanks

**Edit:**
I could of course query the account key directly in the PowerShell task but I would like to understand how to make a securestring output available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you can. securestring type is always omitted. What you should do is use powershell to get the key and use it in the script

Comment: according to https://www.timmerman.it/index.php/using-values-from-your-arm-template-across-your-azure-devops-pipeline-with-powershell/ probably currently it is available

Comment: read the article: `“output_SIoTHubPrimaryKey”:{“type”:”SecureString”}}`, its not

Comment: Sorry I have not seen difference between Output_IoTHubPrimaryKey and Output_SIoTHubPrimaryKey